# Game updates the state based on time. How do I use the time since the user entered the background to execute a task in my view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a game I'm developing that updates the count of creatures every second. However I would like the game to continue to update even when the user enters the background state. In order to do this I would like to use the time since the user entered the background.

I am using the app delegate to store the time in NSUserDefaults with the functions

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
//When application is going into background
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"backgroundTime"];

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
//When application comes back from background state
NSDate *prevDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"backgroundTime"];
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval interval = [currDate timeIntervalSinceDate:prevDate];
NSLog(@"%f",interval);
}
```

In my view controller I am using this method to update counts based on time. How can I implement a function to correctly account for the background time?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self initialize];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(adjustCountsBasedOnTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}




-(void)adjustCountsBasedOnTime{

NSDecimal addition;
NSDecimal mutationIncrease = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1"]decimalValue];
NSDecimalAdd(&_mutationNumber, &_mutationNumber, &mutationIncrease, NSRoundBankers);


NSDecimalMultiply(&addition, &_tierOneCreatureNumber, &_tierOneProductionRate, NSRoundBankers);
NSDecimalAdd(&_sugarNumber, &addition, &_sugarNumber, NSRoundBankers);

NSDecimalMultiply(&addition, &_tierTwoCreatureNumber, &_tierTwoProductionRate, NSRoundBankers);
NSDecimalAdd(&_tierOneCreatureNumber, &_tierOneCreatureNumber, &addition, NSRoundBankers);

NSDecimalMultiply(&addition, &_tierThreeCreatureNumber, &_tierThreeProductionRate, NSRoundBankers);
NSDecimalAdd(&_tierTwoCreatureNumber, &_tierTwoCreatureNumber, &addition, NSRoundBankers);

NSDecimalMultiply(&addition, &_tierFourCreatureNumber, &_tierFourProductionRate, NSRoundBankers);
NSDecimalAdd(&_tierThreeCreatureNumber, &_tierThreeCreatureNumber, &addition, NSRoundBankers);

NSDecimalMultiply(&addition, &_tierFiveCreatureNumber, &_tierFiveProductionRate, NSRoundBankers);
NSDecimalAdd(&_tierFourCreatureNumber, &_tierFourCreatureNumber, &addition, NSRoundBankers);

NSDecimalMultiply(&addition, &_tierSixCreatureNumber, &_tierSixProductionRate, NSRoundBankers);
NSDecimalAdd(&_tierFiveCreatureNumber, &_tierFiveCreatureNumber, &addition, NSRoundBankers);

NSDecimalMultiply(&addition, &_tierSevenCreatureNumber, &_tierSevenProductionRate, NSRoundBankers);
NSDecimalAdd(&_tierSixCreatureNumber, &_tierSixCreatureNumber, &addition, NSRoundBankers);


NSDecimalMultiply(&addition, &_tierEightCreatureNumber, &_tierEightProductionRate, NSRoundBankers);
NSDecimalAdd(&_tierSevenCreatureNumber, &_tierSevenCreatureNumber, &addition, NSRoundBankers);

NSDecimalMultiply(&addition, &_tierNineCreatureNumber, &_tierNineProductionRate, NSRoundBankers);
NSDecimalAdd(&_tierEightCreatureNumber, &_tierEightCreatureNumber, &addition, NSRoundBankers);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simplest idea would be to execute `adjustCountsBasedOnTime`, `interval` times after the app is brought to the foreground.

It is a bit better to have a new method `adjustCountsBasedOnDuration` that does the math and figures out what the new counts should be based on the duration.

Comment: where would be the proper place to add this new method?

Comment: what would be the best way to call such a method to ensure that it only executes after the app returns

Comment: call the method at the point that you currently have the `NSLog`.